Preventing ckeditor5 changes to angled bracket "<" to "&lt;"
using CKeditor 5 for some inline javascript (using Highcharts). I have a javascript function with a variable that contains text with a  tag in the middle of the sentence. The text outputs correctly, but the "" gets switched to <br&gt whenever I switch between SOURCE.
Example code below:
},
text: '2024 Data  40% Growth',
align: 'center',
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
borderColor: 'transparent'
}
This line gets converted to text: '2024 Data <br> 40% Growth',
Appreciate any help, as I don't know where I need to direct ckeditor5 to not convert this text and output as html (respecting the markeup).
Using Drupal authoring section, I tried to configure the settings to make this work, but to no success. I feel it may require me now to go find teh solution in a twig file or js file to correct this.
